# 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'column_types

Tags: cassandra

I installed cassandra on my mac using

```
homebrew install cassandra
```

It installed cassandra version

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Now I connect to cassandra using cqlsh and create a keyspace and a table. when I try to query the table in cqlsh. I get an error

```
'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'column_types
```

I googled the error and found this

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nosql-databases/O3kZmk8AoeY/PooBo9uWDQAJ

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12799

But it is not clear to me what exactly the solution was... the second link seems to suggest that the problem is automatically resolved... but for me it clearly isn't

Comment: Same problem. The system was clean, there should be no older version of anything. I've tried both with the default python and the homebrew one and the problem is still there. Also reinstallation didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just submit a pull request with a fix to the homebrew project:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/10650

Comment: Homebrew merged the fix a brew upgrade cassandra will fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error after upgrading from 3.9 to 3.10 with brew.
Unfortunately I was unable to find the reason nor the answer.
What I researched was to install/uninstall other versions that were also installed via pip (cqlsh, cassandra-driver).

Looking for an alternative I installed cassandra via docker which hopefully is a viable alternative for you too - it works for me.

Using the guide from docker-cassandra - https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/ I setup and connected to cassandra 3.10 with the following two commands (assuming docker ist basically installed from DMG-file).

```
docker run --name cas310 -p 9042:9042 -d cassandra:3.10
docker exec -it cas310 cqlsh
```

This also lets you access cassandra via CQL from outside the container via default cql-port 9042.

Note: Connecting to the dockerized cassandra-instance using cqlsh from the cassandra-version i installed via brew on the host lead to the very same error message as well. So this makes me believe there's some problem with the python-driver packaged with cassandras brew-package.

Comment: how did you find out what other versions where there and how did you uninstall them?

Comment: Depending on your installed python-versions: _pip list_ or _pip3 list_ or try both.

I had cqlsh and cassandra-driver (3.8.0) in _pip list_ as well although cqlsh and the cassandra-driver (3.5.0 as far as i saw) are in the brew-package as well

Comment: I checked. I don't have any other versions. I don't even have pip or pip3 installed.

Comment: for me removing those did not solve the problem either. well as i said i have no explanation for the root-cause. but if you need cassandra quickly you could try the docker alternative. it definitely saved my day because i just could go on.

Comment: i did a little investigation into the brew-formula of cassandra (3.10) and maybe there's an older cassandra-driver still referenced (3.5) instead of the one mentioned in the cassandra-3.10-tar from apache (there it's cassandra-driver 3.7). but i'm no expert in brew-formulas! i dropped a question on the homebrew-project on github.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch I had a conversation with a contributor to the brew cassandra-formula - they fixed it - so just reinstalling cassandra via brew. that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my work macOS laptop a few days ago; fixed as follows (from memory as not at work) :

- `pip uninstall cql`, cqlsh, cassandra-driver, and anything else that looks related.
- `brew uninstall cassandra` (your data will remain ok).
- `brew install python` -- I believe this is the key step due to macOS python causing incompatibilities.
- `brew install cassandra` (this may be sufficient to fix the problem, if not, continue).
- `sudo pip install cqlsh` (I know, the sudo is not good - maybe you can swap this step with the preceding `brew install cassandra` to avoid using sudo).

That fixed the problem for me, but left me with incompatible protocol versions which I've temporarily resolved with `cqlsh --cqlversion="#.#.#"`

Comment: I don't have pip on my machine. if I do `pip uninstall cql` it says `bash pip command not found.`

Comment: I tried the steps listed by you. First I installed python, then pip, then cassandra and finally cqlsh. but it results in same problem. this does not resolve the issue.

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch Hmm.. sorry to hear that.  I'm only back at work in a week, so can't check-up until then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`pip install cassandra-driver --upgrade`